# TList deprecated when compiling for any mobile device

Tags: android, ios, delphi, deprecated, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a Delphi mobile app that contains the following declaration:

```
TWJInformationList = class(TList)
```

When I compile this app for any mobile device (Android, iOS Device 32 bit, iOS Device 64 Bit, and iOS Simulator), I get the following warning:

> [DCC Warning] WJInformation.pas(248): W1000 Symbol 'TList' is deprecated

The above compiles fine on all other Target Platforms (32 bit and 64 bit Windows, and OSX).

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably due to the pointers that are used. Switch to using generic collections, e.g. `TList<T>`, and wave goodbye to `TList`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On all ARC-based platforms, which include Android, iOS, **and** Linux <sup>1</sup> (which is not a mobile platform), the old `Pointer`-based containers, like `Classes.TList` and containers in the `System.Contnrs` unit, are deprecated because they are not safe to use with ARC-based object/interface pointers. You need to use the newer Generics-based counterparts in the `System.Generics.Collections` unit, like `TList<T>`, so the compiler can manage ARC correctly.  A direct replacement for `TList` would be `TList<Pointer>` if you don't want/need ARC handling.

<sup>1: and [*maybe* Windows](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/16563-rad-studio-roadmap-september-2017) in the future.</sup>

Comment: Thank-you that was the solution.

Comment: @Bob If that was the solution, then you should mark Remy's answer as "Accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

With Delphi version 10.4, it looks like System.Contnrs is available on all platforms